# Agregar datos introducidos por el usuario a un csv mediante python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Hola buenas noches a todos!, espero que estén bien. Mi programa trata sobre el manejo de empleados de una empresa por lo que estos empleados tienen distintas características o atributos. Esos atributos o características son: numero,nombre,apellido,edad,hijos,escuelahijos,antiguedad,estudiospropios,experiencia,sueldo,obrasocial

```
def agregar(): #AVERIGUAR COMO AGREGAR DATOS A UN ARCHIVO CSV IMPLEMENTADO EN PANDAS
        nombre = input("Ingrese el nombre del empleado nuevo: ")
        apellido = input("Ingrese el apellido del empleado nuevo: ")
        edad = input("Ingrese la edad del empleado nuevo: ")
        hijos = input("Ingrese la cantidad de hijos del empleado nuevo: ")
        escuelaHijos = input("Ingrese el colegio al que asisten los hijos del empleado nuevo: ")
        antiguedad = str(0)
        estudiosPropios = input("Ingrese los estudios que posee el empleado nuevo: ")
        experiencia = input("Ingrese la experiencia con la que cuenta el empleado nuevo: ")
        sueldo = input("Ingrese el sueldo que recibe: ")
        obrasocial = input("Ingrese su obra social: ")
        df = pd.read_csv('planeamiento3.csv')
        numeros = df
        numeroAlto = numeros[numeros.numero == numeros.numero.max()]
        numeroAlto = int(numeroAlto) + 1




        print('\n' + "El empleado ha sido cargado con exito")
```

Mediante la introducción de los datos (el usuario elige el nombre, el apellido, la edad, etc) tengo que agregar esos datos al csv y finalmente tiene que decirme que lo cargo exitosamente. Las líneas que sacan el numero mas alto sirven para que cuando cargue el empleado nuevo no se repita el numero con otro empleados. Por ejemplo, Javier tiene asignado el numero de empleado 10 y cuando agrego a Fernando no puede tener el 10 por que ya lo tiene Javier, sino que tendría que tener el 11. Desde ya muchas gracias y espero que alguien pueda ayudarme.

[Carpeta de Google Drive con los archivos][Solicitar acceso previamente]

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1olaBUjYswaoTfMbR8p6y4mjiAdWgFRmA?usp=sharing

Comment: creo que hay muchas cosas que se pueden mejorar, voy a comer en un rato vuelvo para tu problema!

Comment: por favor añade el `.csv`!

Comment: mi solución te sirvió? si no es así puedes decírmelo para mejorarla

Answer (score 1):

Bueno me encanta simplificar tu código :)
Simplifique la forma de pedir los datos haciendo uso de un ciclo `for`, si no te molesta que salga algo como `Ingrese el escuelahijos del empleado nuevo:`  puedes usar mi solución o implementar la tuya en base a la mia.

Primero obtenemos los campos del archivo `.csv`, si iteramos en el propio archivo esto nos dara como resultado el nombre de las columnas, lo cual nos servirá para hacer el ciclo antes dicho.

```py
import pandas as pd
#leemos el archivo
df = pd.read_csv('planeamiento3.csv')

#obtenemos las columnas
datos = [columna for columna in df]
```

Creamos un diccionario para almacenar los datos obtenidos por el usuario

```py
#diccionario para guardar datos de los empleados
info_empleado = {}
```

Ahora iteramos y guardamos todo en el diccionario, recuerda que el diccionario se commpone por `key/value` de esta forma `dic[key]=value`

```py
for dato in datos:
    #preguntamos
    info = input(f"Ingrese el {dato} del empleado nuevo: ")
    #agregamos al diccionario
    info_empleado[dato] = info
```

Para finalizar, solo nos falta comprobar que el dato se inserto y el archivo se guardo correctamente. Para eso hacemos uso de un `try/except`

```py
#hacemos un try/except por si ocurre un error
try:
    #agregamos al DataFrame
    df = df.append(info_empleado,ignore_index=True)
    print(df)
    print("Datos agregados :)")

    #guardamos el archivo actualizado
    df.to_csv('planeamiento3.csv')
    print("Archivo actualizado")

#si ocurre algun error en proceso anterior, se ejecute este bloque
except:
    print("Ha ocurrido un error\nSaliendo...")
    exit()#salimos del programa
```

Dando como resultado:

```
Ingrese el nombre del empleado nuevo: chris
Ingrese el apellido del empleado nuevo: yopi
Ingrese el edad del empleado nuevo: 16
Ingrese el hijos del empleado nuevo: 0
Ingrese el escuelahijos del empleado nuevo: nose
Ingrese el antiguedad del empleado nuevo: 0
Ingrese el estudiospropios del empleado nuevo: programador
Ingrese el experiencia del empleado nuevo: 3
Ingrese el sueldo del empleado nuevo: 0
Ingrese el obrasocial del empleado nuevo: none


      nombre   apellido edad hijos escuelahijos antiguedad estudiospropios experiencia sueldo obrasocial
0  christian  velasquez   16     0         nose          3     programador           3      0       nose
1       jose    alberto   20     1         nose          5       diseñador           1      0       nose
2      chris       yopi   16     0         nose          0     programador           3      0       none
```

El ultimo registro es el que se insertó.

**observaciones en tu código**

- No hace falta usar una función para obtener el ultimo registro, pues al usar el método `append()` de pandas este solo lo inserta al final y crea un nuevo índice, tal y como se aprecia en el resultado.
- Es recomendable cargar primero el archivo (antes que todo), si vas a usar el mismo archivo en todo tu código, es mejor que lo pongas en las primeras líneas (después de importar `pandas`)
- **MUESTRA TU CSV**, estoy inventadme los datos, eso no es bueno, es preferible que muestres los datos para entender mejor y dar la mejor estructura.

Por ultimo, una regla de python

> Escribe la menor cantidad de código siempre que sea posible

Comment: Como siempre un trabajo impecable en cuanto a pandas, pero bien chistoso se ve el "el" antes del nombre de los datos jajaja

Comment: @AnkiJedi gracias, jaja son efectos secundarios de generalizar algo, creo que se podría arreglar si se utiliza otra expresión para pedir el dato.

Comment: @Christian recien lo pude probar y hay una fallta en que cuando quiero ver todos los empleados me tira un error, queres que te adjunte el archivo csv? si queres tambien el .py no tengo problema

Comment: @MellisRusman si mejor pon todo, incluyendo el error que te genera

Comment: @Christian ahi te agregue el archivo csv y el py el csv se llama planeamiento3.csv y el py se llama planeamiento.py. Te pido que me solicites acceso ya que al link solo pueden acceder quien yo lo autorice (es para que no se roben mi codigo)

Comment: @MellisRusman Listo ya lo hice, lo siento por la demora >_<

Comment: @MellisRusman dado que tu problema es diferente al planteado aqui, sugiero que hagas otra pregunta